# Is it possible to launch tests on save using gogland jetbrains?

Tags: goland

The question is quite simple: Is it possible to launch tests on save using gogland jetbrains?

I know that I can launch `go fmt` or `go imports` from the `Settings => Go => On Save` panel. Is there a way to add other actions ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

In the picture below of the test runner

[image: test runner interface]

Click on the third button from top to bottom on the left side and that will trigger the last test configuration used after you save your changes.